# Vantagens de Watch em comparação com Break point

Tags: visual-studio, debug, watch, breakpoints

Visto que é possível avaliar o valor de uma variável inserindo um *break point* aonde ela será usada, não vejo nenhuma vantagem aparente.

- Existe alguma vantagem de se usar *watch* ao invés de break point
  para *debugar* o código?  Quais?
- Existe alguma situação onde o uso de watch e somente ele seja realmente necessário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Existe alguma vantagem de se usar watch ao invés de break point para debugar o código? Quais?

Quando você tiver que verificar o valor de cinco variáveis de uma vez, ou do estado da instância que executa a sua lógica, ou de propriedades de propriedades de propriedades de propriedades, você perceberá o valor do `watch`.

> Existe alguma situação onde o uso de watch e somente ele seja realmente necessário?

Você nunca vai conseguir usar `watch` se não estiver em modo de depuração. O mais próximo disso, quando você não está em modo de depuração, é utilizar alguma forma de log para guardar um histórico dos valores das variáveis conforme o código é executado. Mas isso gera lixo no armazenamento ao longo do tempo.